# Can you call verilog code from a c program running on a soft processor on an FPGA

Tags: fpga, c, verilog, nios-ii

I have a soft NIOS II processor instantiated on an Altera FPGA. I have 4 JTAG pins connected from the FPGA to a FTDI chip (lets call them A1, A2, A3, A4). I have the JTAG pins from 2 MCUs connected to the FPGA also (lets call them B1, B2, B3, B4 and C1, C2, C3, C4).

In software running on the NIOS I want to be able to select which two sets of pins I want to connect (i.e. A to B or A to C).

You have to do pins assignments in verilog though. Is there a way to call a block of verilog code from a c program running on the NIOS?

Comment: Can't you have a shared pin between both ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just create a MUX in Verilog and then use processor I/O to control the MUX?

Comment: @Tut, thanks this is a good idea. You suggesting to use a 2:1 multiplexer?

Comment: You would need a 2::1 MUX for each of the four individual signals. Since FPGA multiplexer implementations are digital in nature you will have to look carefully at the directionality of each of the signals in question so that the multiplexer inputs and outputs feed in the correct way for each signal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You can't call Verilog (which is hardware) from C.

(Well, you can in a simulator, but that's another story).

But you can write data to a memory address in C.

In Verilog, you can map that memory address to a register, and connect that register's outputs to the control inputs of a multiplexer, to select between different signals. That's a simple piece of hardware design.

Now, by writing to that address in your C program, you can select different signals.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the capability of creating custom instructions for the NIOS processor. It's available in the Altera tools. I believe that feature may allow you to do what you want.